# How to make column to Upper too and remove symbol _ in collection laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

So I want to make column name and value to UPPERCASE

example:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'Sally'],
    ['school_name' => 'Arkansas'],
    ['age' => 28]
]);

$flattened = $collection->flatMap(function ($values) {
    return array_map('strtoupper', $values);
});

$flattened->all();

// ['name' => 'SALLY', 'school_name' => 'ARKANSAS', 'age' => '28'];
```

I want to make 'name, school_name, age' to Upper too. That code only make the values to upper but not for the column name

Comment: will this help u array_change_key_case($input_array, CASE_UPPER)

Comment: it works, thanks, but how to remove the underscore "_"

Comment: use str_replace. follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391869/replacing-array-key-spaces-with-underscores-in-multidimensional-array/13396121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr = ['name' => 'Sally', 'school_name' => 'Arkansas', 'age' => '28'];

$out = [];
$replace = '';
array_walk($arr, function($val, $key) use (&$out, $replace) {
    $key2 = strtoupper($key);
    $key2 = str_replace('_', $replace, $key2);
    $out[$key2] = strtoupper($val);
});

echo "before:\n";
print_r($arr);

echo "after:\n";
print_r($out);
```

gives result:

```
before:
Array
(
    [name] => Sally
    [school_name] => Arkansas
    [age] => 28
)
after:
Array
(
    [NAME] => SALLY
    [SCHOOLNAME] => ARKANSAS
    [AGE] => 28
)
```

change `$replace` to whatever character you want or leave as an empty string to remove the underscore.

PHP Manual References:

1. [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)
2. [strtoupper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)
3. [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
4. [Anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
5. [Passing by Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection = collect([
        ['name' => 'Sally'],
        ['school_name' => 'Arkansas'],
        ['age' => 28]
    ]);


$flattened = $collection->flatMap(function ($items) {
    //iterating over the array
    foreach($items as $itemKey => $itemValue):
        //replaccing the _ with null
        $itemKey = str_replace(['_'],[],$itemKey);
        //converting the keys and value to uppercase
        return [ mb_strtoupper($itemKey) => mb_strtoupper($itemValue) ];

    endforeach;
});

$flattened->all();
```

Actual VS Result

```
Collection {#518 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "name" => "Sally"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "school_name" => "Arkansas"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      "age" => 28
    ]
  ]
}
Collection {#600 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "NAME" => "SALLY"
    "SCHOOLNAME" => "ARKANSAS"
    "AGE" => "28"
  ]
}
```

If You like to Cleaup the Code Here is the Macro that i have Created

```
\Illuminate\Support\Collection\Collection::macro('makeUpperAndReplace',function($replaceItems = []){

    return $this->flatMap(function ($items) use ($replaceItems) {
        //iterating over the array
        foreach($items as $itemKey => $itemValue):
            //replaccing the $replaceItems with null
            $itemKey = str_replace($replaceItems,[],$itemKey);
            //converting the keys and value to uppercase

            return [ mb_strtoupper($itemKey) => mb_strtoupper($itemValue) ];

        endforeach;
    });
});
```

And Macro Can be Used as

```
$collection->makeUpperAndReplace(['_','-'])->dd();
```

Comment if there is Any Issues

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $collection = array(
'name' => 'Sally',
'school_name' => 'Arkansas',
'age' => 28);
$collection = array_change_key_case($collection, CASE_UPPER);
fixArrayKey($collection);
print_r($collection);
function fixArrayKey(&$collection){
$collection = array_combine(array_map('_map',array_keys($collection)),array_values($collection));
foreach($collection as $key=>$val)
{
    if(is_array($val)) fixArrayKey($collection[$key]);
}
}
function _map($str){return str_replace("_","",$str);}
?>
```

Result

```
Array ( [NAME] => Sally [SCHOOLNAME] => Arkansas [AGE] => 28 )
```